# Failed and error messages changed "2 UNKNOWN:" grpc-node

Tags: node.js, grpc

```
 Expected value to equal:
   "Zone doesn't exist"
 Received:
   "2 UNKNOWN: Zone doesn't exist"
```

My tests failed all of a sudden. Appending `2 UNKNOWN:` before everything.

Answer (score 0):

Backward compatibility issue while using `^1.7.2`, which has updated to  1.8.4.

grpc-node 1.8.4 Added **error code name to status error messages**.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/pull/126

Which results in the following error.

Replace

```
  try {
    await sayHello()
  } catch (error) {
    message = error.message
  }
```

to

```
  try {
    await sayHello()
  } catch (error) {
    message = error.details
  }
```

From `message` to `details`.